# Java 6 and Java 7 yield different results, if an attempt is made to set a value to the value[] field of the String class using reflection

Tags: java, string, reflection, java-7, java-6

The following code attempts to set a value to the `private final char value[]` field of the String class **using Java 7**.

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public final class Test 
{
    static
    {
        try
        {
            Field value = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
            value.setAccessible(true);
            value.set("Hello World", value.get("1234567890"));
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

and it silently displays `1234567890` on the console and there is no question about it.

---

When I try to do the same thing using **Java 6** like the following,

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public final class Test
{
    static
    {
        try
        {
            Field value = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
            value.setAccessible(true);
            value.set("Hello World", value.get("1234567890"));
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        catch (SecurityException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

it causes the following exception to be thrown.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

It works when the length of `value.get("1234567890")` in this statement `value.set("Hello World", value.get("1234567890"));` is grater than or equal to the String `Hello World`

For example,

If the following statement (as in the preceding code snippet)

```
value.set("Hello World", value.get("1234567890"));
```

is replaced by something like the following

```
value.set("Hello World", value.get("12345678901"));
```

So why doesn't this work with **Java 6** (or might be lower, I didn't try) when the length of the second parameter of the `set()` method is less than the first one?

BTW, I can understand that dealing with private fields with reflection in this way is not recommended at all and is worst.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So why doesn't this work with Java 6 (or might be lower, I didn't try) when the length of the second parameter of the set() method is less than the first one?

In Java 6, you're managing to set the `value` character array to the new reference - but you're not changing the *other* fields which specify the section of the `char[]` which the string refers to.

I can't remember the exact field names, but it's something like this:

```
char[] value;
int offset;
int count;
```

So for a string which "covers" the entire character array, `offset` would be 0 and `count` would be `value.length`. Now if you replace `value` with a *shorter* `char[]`, but don't change `count`, then `offset + count` is beyond the end of the array... it's outside the bounds of the array. This is done so that operations like `substring` don't need to copy the character data - they just create a new object which refers to the existing array, with different offset / count values.

In Java 7 from update 5 onwards, strings don't have this offset/count concept; instead, each string has its own character array and the start and end are implicit. I suspect that's why it works for you in Java 7.